# I'll be hanged if

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:

> I'll be hanged if it isn't the Stacey store again, shouted the man
>   next me on the engine as the horses lunged up the avenue and stopped
>   at the allotted hydrant.

This is a hyperbolic saying, but I'm a little bit confused, is the speaker sure that its the Stacey store or he isn't sure? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cf. "Example sentences with 'damned if I know'" https://glosbe.com/en/en/damned%20if%20I%20know

Comment: "I'll be hanged if ..." means "Well, if it isn't ...".

Comment: I'll be hanged if it isn't is like two negatives. I do not want to be hanged, but I won't, because *it is*. Since it is the Stacey store, I will not be hanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker is sure that it *is* the Stacey store.

He is so sure that it is the Stacey store, that if he is wrong, he will be executed by hanging. Obviously, this is hyperbole - he won't *really* be executed.

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the right understaning

Comment: This is correct as far as I know, but a reference would be good. I can't find anything exact, although Cambridge dictionaries online has "I'll be hanged if I know" = "used to say that you certainly do not know"   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-ll-be-hanged-if-i-know

Comment: Yes me too i checked the reference, but the examples there made me confused

Comment: [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_isn%27t) ***if it isn't...*** (past tense *if it wasn't*) - Observes, **with some surprise**, that a specified thing or person is present. *"Why, if it isn't Bill! Come on in, Bill!"*. Where ***Why = I'll be damned = I'll be hanged***.